# Probablity weighted ReplaceAll

Tags: replacement, rule

I'm looking for an elegant way of doing a probability weighted replacement rule,

something like this

```
f[x_] :=  x /.  {1,2,3,4} -> {50%{ 4,3,2,1} ,50%{1,3,2,4}}
```

Using an If statement and generating a RandomReal will be very clumsy as I want different probabilities depending on the pattern I want replaced.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `RandomChoice` to randomly select an item from a list.

You can even randomly select an operator and apply it. For example:

```
f[x_List] := RandomChoice[{Reverse, Identity}][x]

Table[f[{1, 2, 3, 4}], {10}]
```

returns:

```
{{4, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 
  4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 
  3, 4}}
```

As pointed by @WReach you can also assign a weight to each choice (weights are automatically normalized, i.e. they not need to sum to 1). For example:

```
f[x_List] := RandomChoice[{3, 1} -> {Reverse, Identity}][x]
Table[f[{1, 2, 3, 4}], {10}]
```

returns:

```
{{4, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 2, 
  1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 
  3, 4}}
```

Your specific pseudo-code can be replaced with something like:

```
f[x_] := x /. {1, 2, 3, 4} :> RandomChoice[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}]
Table[f[{1, 2, 3, 4}], {10}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use Condition:

```
Replace[foo, {foo_ /; RandomReal[] < p :> bar, foo_ :> baz}]
```

where `p` is the probability you want to give to the first replacement.

This is somewhat similar to using an `If`, but I find it somewhat more idiomatic. I would also avoid using `ReplaceAll`, when you actually want `Replace` as `ReplaceAll` might recurse down the whole expression.

You could also explore random function definition:

```
ff[x_] /; RandomReal[] < p := bar
ff[x_] := baz
```

Not completely unlike [Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_(programming_language))